# What does sloth-tech mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a phrase where this combination is used in a book:

> The  panels  kept  on  growing,  until  they  required  complex,  sloth-tech
>   machinery  to  hold  them  aloft  against  gravity  and  weather.

Could you explain what "sloth-tech" here actually means?

Comment: Have you looked up **sloth** in the dictionary?  The author is coining a phrase based on the animal's association with slowness.

Comment: @TRomano yes, I know what a sloth animal or person is :) So you mean that sloth-tech means "slow" and "cumbersome" in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from a piece of science fiction by Alistair Reynolds. Depictions of technologies in the fictional worlds of such writing may use nicely coined new terms and fictional slang, often without definition or immediate explanation. Part of the fun is to infer the author's intent. Sometimes the meanings are explained later in the book. [We might consider the Lewis Carroll poem Jabberwocky as a similar flight of fancy, many of the terms are explained later in the narrative.]

Here we are presumably meant to imagine some high-tech machinery that moves extremely slowly, and perhaps with the appearance of organic behaviour.

Comment: yeah, you are rigth. I got it like this. Translating that short novel from English language so trying to think such things over thoroughly :)

Comment: Take note that Sloth is capitalized in the original -- it's intended as a proper noun or adjective.  Based on this story alone, we have no idea whether the Sloth are an alien race, an intergalactic civilization, a set of techniques based on as-yet-undiscovered fields of science, or something even more difficult to imagine.  Nevertheless, it's the kind of thing that deserves a capital in English.